# Are there any factors that limit the ability to change an element's display beyond proper code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

So I have a script within my html (using django framework to retrieve db data) that looks at the total number of data entries, and changes the div display of 12 different cards to none for any cards I created beyond the number of entries. My script is functionally working for changing the innerhtml of the items below, however, it is not changing the display (console element shows display: block still). From everything I have read, this appears to be the correct way to change this. If it is written correctly, is there a reason the script would not accept these changes that I am missing?

```
} else if (projQuant = 4) {
            c5.style.display = 'none';
            c6.style.display = 'none';
            c7.style.display = 'none';
            c8.style.display = 'none';
            c9.style.display = 'none';
            c10.style.display = 'none';
            c11.style.display = 'none';
            c12.style.display = 'none';
            c1ProjName.innerHTML=finProjNames[0];
            c1LastMod.innerHTML=finLastMods[0];
            c2ProjName.innerHTML=finProjNames[1];
            c2LastMod.innerHTML=finLastMods[1];
            c3ProjName.innerHTML=finProjNames[2];
            c3LastMod.innerHTML=finLastMods[2];
            c4ProjName.innerHTML=finProjNames[3];
            c4LastMod.innerHTML=finLastMods[3];
```

here is how I defined the cards (c1, c2, c3, etc):

```
var c1 = document.getElementById('cardOne');
var c1BGpic = document.getElementById('cardOneBGPic');
var c1ProjName = document.getElementById('cardOneProjName');
var c1LastMod = document.getElementById('cardOneLastMod');
var c2 = document.getElementById('cardTwo');
var c2BGpic = document.getElementById('cardTwoBGPic');
var c2ProjName = document.getElementById('cardTwoProjName');
var c2LastMod = document.getElementById('cardTwoLastMod');
```

display output of the first 6 cards:
[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkKM2.png)

Answer (score 1):

`if (projQuant = 4)` should be `if (projQuant == 4)`, since `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.

Since that's an `else if`, I'll wager you have other `if`s that have the same typo, so only the first one of them will ever be executed since it would assign `projQuant = 1`, and then that'd be true, e.g.

```
if(projQuant = 1) {
  // Will always be run
} else if(projQuant = 2) {
  // Can never run (in else, and the first block was run)
} else if(projQuant = 3) {
  // Can never run (in else, and the first block was run)
} else if(projQuant = 4) {
  // Can never run (in else, and the first block was run)
}
```

You should learn how to use JavaScript debugging techniques; the most rudimentary one is a `console.log("I'm here!");`; if you put that in the block that you expect to have run, you would have likely not seen that printed out, ergo it hadn't been run. (The `debugger;` statement is even more powerful; it will break the script execution at that point and you can inspect and modify the script state.)

Secondly, please use arrays for those elements so you don't even *need* that `if`. Assuming you can give your cards a `class="my-card"` (and the name elements `"proj-name"`),

```
const cards = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".my-card"));
// ...
for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  if(i < projQuant) {
    cards[i].style.display = 'block';
    cards[i].querySelector(".proj-name").innerHTML = projNames[i];
    // etc.
  } else {
    cards[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Hmmm, you were correct, that was how my if statements looked. But in projQuant = 1, I only retrieved the text data for the first card. Any idea why 4 cards would be filled out with innerHTML and not just the first, if the first was the only one that would be read? The cards only addressed their equivalent num, so projQuant = 1 only returned ProjName and LastMod for card one (not 2/3/4).

Comment: No idea without seeing the rest of your code, or how those cards might be filled out by your Django template beforehand. Remember I had to use my crystal ball to guess at your if/elseifs too.